Where is the Rambam's source in Hilchot Melachim Umilhamoteyhem 5 that a defensive war is a milchemet mitzvah?
"אֵין הַמֶּלֶךְ נִלְחָם תְּחִלָּה אֶלָּא מִלְחֶמֶת מִצְוָה. וְאֵי זוֹ הִיא מִלְחֶמֶת מִצְוָה זוֹ מִלְחֶמֶת שִׁבְעָה עֲמָמִים. וּמִלְחֶמֶת עֲמָלֵק. וְעֶזְרַת יִשְׂרָאֵל מִיַּד צָר שֶׁבָּא עֲלֵיהֶם. וְאַחַר כָּךְ נִלְחָם בְּמִלְחֶמֶת הָרְשׁוּת וְהִיא הַמִּלְחָמָה שֶׁנִּלְחָם עִם שְׁאָר הָעַמִּים כְּדֵי לְהַרְחִיב גְּבוּל יִשְׂרָאֵל וּלְהַרְבּוֹת בִּגְדֻלָּתוֹ וְשִׁמְעוֹ:
A king should not wage other wars before a milchemet mitzvah. What is considered as milchemet mitzvah? The war against the seven nations who occupied Eretz Yisrael, the war against Amalek, and a war fought to assist Israel from an enemy which attacks them.
Afterwards, he may wage a milchemet hareshut, i.e. a war fought with other nations in order to expand the borders of Israel or magnify its greatness and reputation."
What is the source that a war to assist Israel from an enemy which attacks them (i.e. a defensive war) is a milchemet mitzvah? Is there one, beyond the simple reasoning/first principles thinking that it's not a milchemet hareshut (discretionary war) if it's to fight off an enemy that is attacking?

https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.44b.8?lang=bi&with=all

@Sholom Is a defensive war the same as a preemptive was?

@Sholom So Rambam is taking Rabbi Yehuda's opinion on the matter?
